# Cannot identify string as part of set

Tags: python, parsing, set

I am trying to automatically detect the starting point for parsing some data into a list - specifically I want to start collecting only integers. I have a lot of data to go through and the files can be .txt or .csv usually starting with several rows of information on the data collection itself.

I am using a function to check if the data contains only integers / delimeters like so:

```
def check_str(input):
    allow = set("0123456789\t eE-+.,;")
    validation = set((input))
    if validation.issubset(allow):
        out = True
    else:
        out = False
    return out
```

Now, this works for test strings like:

```
test = '435.76   568.21'
```

But it doesn't work on the actual data from the .txt file:

```
341.09  75.97
341.46  75.97
341.84  75.97
342.22  17.28
342.59  8.91
```

[Output of check_string on actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dyDI.png)

I'm not really sure what the problem is, I have included tab and white space in my set so I cannot understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: FYI you should not call a variable `input` or any other built-in name, because you then will be unable to access the built-in `input` function, for example.

Comment: The data from your text file contains characters that are not in your allow set, e.g. > and < and all those words. You don't allow letters that aren't "e" or "E" either.

Comment: @RandomDavis - thanks, I know that but I just used it for speed.

Comment: @ArtieVandelay - in my code there is a for loop with if statements to detect when the wanted data has been reached

Comment: @SeanK Try to allow `\n` (you probably have newlines inside string too)

Comment: You can also directly `return validation.issubset(allow)` instead of the `out = ...`/`if`/`else`.

Comment: You could use set subtraction to find out which invalid characters are in your input. Try `print(validation - allow)`.

Comment: Can you show this for loop you mentioned? It's probably there where the issue is, because this function seems to do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Please don't delete your question if you have an answer (scipy n-gaussian question); it might be useful for someone else, and it feels rude to get an answer and then run off leaving no trace.

Comment: Ah okay, I deleted it because it was more of a typo / not checking the syntax properly. Will undelete it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that each row contains '\r\n' at the end:

i.e.

```
'1.301237305e+03,4.503491255e-06\r\n'
```

adding this to the set fixed the issue.

Thanks to Andrej Kesely for some insight.